# Setting a Label Function for ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**Is there a way to use a label function for the the Items placed in a combo box?**

Currently it uses the `ToString()` to get the label. As an example say you have a `ComboBox` that is backed by a list objects of type `Person`:

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public class Person {

        public string fname { get; set; }

        public string mname { get; set; }

        public string lname { get; set; }

        public Person(string fname, string mname, string lname) {
            this.fname = fname;
            this.mname = mname;
            this.lname = lname;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return this.lname +", " + this.fname + " "+ this.mname;
        }
    }
}
```

But now you want to the text for each person to be just `this fname + " "+ this.mname[0]+" "+this.lname` in some places. Ideally I would like to be able to add a method to the backing XAML cs file like:

```
public string GetLabel(Person item) {
    return item.fname + " " + item.mname[0] + " " + item.lname;
}
```

and then somehow point it the ComboBox at the method in the cs file.

---

Here is a sample XAML file and XAML.cs if it is any help:
**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="250">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="items" Height="22" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
   public partial class MainWindow : Window {

        public List<Person> persons { get; set; }

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.persons = new List<Person>();
            persons.Add(new Person("First", "Middle", "Last"));
            persons.Add(new Person("John", "Jacob", "Jingleheimer"));
            persons.Add(new Person("First", "Middle", "Last"));

            this.items.DataContext = this.persons;
        }


        public string GetLabel(Person item) {
            return item.fname + " " + item.mname[0] + " " + item.lname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider change the function name ItemLabel to GetLabel(). Will this make more sense?

Comment: @David GetLabel() is a better name

Comment: have you considered using mvvm?

Comment: @Daniel, I am just getting started with .Net coming from a Java and Flex background, and while I am familiar with MVVM (admittedly still trying to wrap my head around it), I do not really see how that solves my current problem.

Comment: @jschoen with mvvm, you can do this with data binding.

Comment: @Daniel If you could provide an example I would appreciate it.

Comment: @jschoen, so the interesting part of your design is that you're placing the display value of a model in the `Window`. But honestly, that functionality belongs right where you have it - in the model - considering separation of concerns. Another approach is adding a property to the model, even as an implementation of an interface for example, named `Label` and it returns what's in the `ToString` and just add the `DisplayMemberPath` to the binding and set it to `Label`.

Comment: @Michael Without getting into an argument about where GetLabel() actually should belong, the fact remains that what I am trying to accomplish is to be able to allow the view to dictate how the Person object label is formatted for display. Essentially not returning what is in the ToString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a ViewModel to make this much more straight forward, but if you want to do what you are asking you could just make another property on your `Person` class that you bind up to on your ComboBox.

```
public class Person 
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string mname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return item.fname + " " + item.mname[0] + " " + item.lname;
        }
    }

    public Person(string fname, string mname, string lname) 
    {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.mname = mname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
}
```

Then you can just use this XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="items" Height="22" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding} DisplayMemberPath="FullName"/>
```

Again I suggest you learn more about MVVM.

I Hope this helps.

---

Edit

Ok, you asked if I could show you how to do it using MVVM, so here it goes.

First we have our `Person` class which is our model (I renamed properties and added an Id field because I could)

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        FirstName = firstName;
        MiddleName = middleName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Notice that I didn't pollute my model with the FullName property as this is purely for display, so we will put it in a ViewModel.

Here is the `PersonViewModel` (note the ViewModelBase in this case is just a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Person person { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get { return person.Id; } }

    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return person.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            if (person.FirstName != value)
            {
                person.FirstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string MiddleName
    {
        get { return person.MiddleName; }
        set
        {
            if (person.MiddleName != value)
            {
                person.MiddleName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MiddleName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return person.LastName; }
        set
        {
            if (person.LastName != value)
            {
                person.LastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName { get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName + " " + MiddleName; } }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        person = new Person();
    }

    public PersonViewModel(Person inPerson)
    {
        person = inPerson;
    }
}
```

It basically wraps our Person Class with Properties that are Raising PropertyChanged notifications (needed if you want to update the screen when a property changes).  It also adds the new `FullName` property.

Next we have a MainViewModel because I don't want to put code into the Code Behind page of the MainWindow.  It just declares our `List<PersonViewModel>` and populates it.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public List<PersonViewModel> People { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Get the people list from your data provider (in this case returns IEnumerable<Person>)
        var peopleList = DataProvider.GetPeople();

        // Wrap each person in a PersonViewModel to make them more UI friendly
        People = peopleList.Select(p => new PersonViewModel(p)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Finally, we have our MainWindow with the `ComboBox` on it.

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MVVM_Sample.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{DynamicResource ViewModel}">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="Id" Height="22" Width="200" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that I declare an instance of `MainViewModel` in the Resources and set it to the `DataContext` of the Window.  This makes my Binding statements look to the MainViewModel for the values.

I know this seems a bit long winded for such a simple example, but it makes much more sense when things start to get complicated and it helps keep the needed separation of concerns.  Both MVVM and XAML are awesome tools, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: If you happen to have to time to convert the above example in to a MVVM example it would greatly appreciated. I think it would clear a lot of things up for me.

Comment: It is hard to boil a concept as large as MVVM down to a trivial example, but I'll think about what could be done.

Comment: There you go.  I added a sample to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It actually makes everything I have been reading make a lot more sense. The examples provided in other sources I have seen started off too complex, to really understand the structure. So this is a great help.